# What happened to my delegated Gmail account?

Tags: gmail, google-apps-email

We're using Gmail for our domain and I have access to both my own account and a delegated one. Normally, I can choose to view the delegated account and it opens in a new tab.

Today when I tried that, it just opened another tab to the same email account - my own account. The same thing happened to another person who has delegated access.

I went to the admin console for our users, and the delegated account was not even listed.

How can I get access to the delegated account again?

Answer (score 1):

## Log in directly

I didn't know the password to log in to the account directly, but I got another team member to do so. When he did, he had to enter a CAPTCHA.

Once he had logged in successfully, the delegated account showed up in the Admin console again and I was able to get to it as usual.

I'm not sure why this happened. Maybe someone had been trying to guess the password and Google had locked the account somehow, but nothing indicated that to me. The behavior I saw seems like a bug.

In any case, logging in directly made things work as usual for us.

Comment: I submitted a support form to Google, linking them to this discussion, so they should be aware of the bug.